# " button instead of < in my external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, character

Recent weeks I was using my keyboard with Turkish language. [image: keyboard]

I would like to write " when I clicked the top left button, under the escape key. I don't want to write < character.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I changed my keyboard type without knowing it. So corrected it on System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Change Keyboard Type.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a way of changing the keyboard bindings. This might be possible depending ont he manufacturer.

Other options would be to create a short cut for the symbol you want. There are three double quoates I know of and if this is for coding you will want to make sure to pick the right one. But say you want the straight double quotes, then you can create a short cut that writes out the symbol.

Alternatively you can you can use the Alt codes tp produce it. Like Alt 0148 for "

Comment: how am i gonna change my keyboard bindings? because i have tried once before.

Comment: What is the brand-mpdel of your keyboard and Operating System you are on?

Comment: mac os high sierra 10.13.6 (17G4015)

mumuso keyboard

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT3bEsVWnIPgL5AKUxiD5E8TpBc4hqciILHshQn3oxDgimWpIU8